# I get this error [ERROR] Ld/Users/user1/Document/Programador/build/iphone/build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Programador.app/Programador normal

Tags: javascript, titanium-sdk

I get this error when running my iOS emulator

```
[ERROR] warning: conditional compilation flags do not have values in Swift; they are either present or absent (rather than 'TI_VERSION=12.0.0')
[ERROR] ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] Ld/Users/user1/Document/Programador/build/iphone/build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Programador.app/Programador normal (in target 'Programador' from project 'Programador')
[ERROR] (1 failure)
 
Process exited with 1
```

Titanium Version 12.0.0 GA

Answer (score 0):

Please use the latest version (12.1.2) as that fixes issues in the build process. 12.0.0 came out in December 22 and multiple compile errors were found and fixed during those months.

If still have issues with the latest version it might be good to open an issue on https://github.com/tidev/titanium-sdk/issues

As a workaround (in case it won't work with 12.1.2) you can always go back to Xcode 14.2.

Comment: I updated it and I still get the same error :,c